# Does it harm my credit score if open multiple current accounts?

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account

I'm currently trying out mobile app banks Monzo and Revolut, but I would also like to try N26 and Starling; all these on top of my regular current account. Would opening all these accounts affect my credit score? Would closing the accounts affect it too?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably none of these have an overdraft or credit facility?

Comment: Monzo does, I'm not sure about the others

Answer (score 1):

For my particular case I opened accounts with Revolut, N26, Fineco and Starling, the middle two fairly close to each other. None of them have an overdraft. I didn't see an impact on my credit score.